# Securing an internal tcp proxy

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, proxy, tcp

I am developing a TCP-Proxy in C#/.NET using dotNetty (Port of Netty). The proxy is translating messages between two different systems. It will be hosted on a server in the company network, so it is not exposed to the internet.

I am wondering what precautions I should take regarding information security. I thought of using TLS to encrypt the communication between the server and the two systems. I also thought of creating and using a specific client certificate, so only the intended system can connect to the server. Is that enough or too much? Is there another angle of attack that I might've overlooked?

Comment: What is your threat model? What are you trying to protect against? Are internal threats in your scope? Are the systems connected to your proxy hostile? What kind of data is transmitted through the proxy? What security properties are required? (confidentiality, integrity, availability) There is so much we don't know to answer properly, you might need to be more specific if you want useful answers

Comment: What do you want to secure *against*? Just throwing security controls at something is not going to work.